# Manipulate indices in a SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to shift the indices of a SparseTensor in Tensorflow. Is there a way to alter a SparseTensor's indices?

```python
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# build graph
x = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='x')
sparse_indices = x.indices

# This line does not work:
sparse_indices[:, 1] = sparse_indices[:, 1] + 1

shifted_x = tf.SparseTensor(indices=sparse_indices, 
                            values=x.values,
                            dense_shape=[2,20])
# start session
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
indices = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 1]], dtype=np.int64)
values = np.array([1, 1], dtype=np.float32)
shape = np.array([2, 10], dtype=np.int64)
shifted = session.run(shifted_x,
                      {x:tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)})
```